# How do I remove the border under the active tab

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I remove the underline on the active tab? This is the codepen: https://codepen.io/centem/pen/XWmPbVa
I tried styling the .nav-link.active to no avail. Trying to make it look like actual folder tabs. Thank  you.

```
<div class="container"
<div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2>Charts</h2>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="nav-items">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            Column Chart
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-items">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            Treemap
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-items">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            Donut Chart
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-items">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            Time Series
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab1">
                      <h3>Column Chart <small>Lorem ipsum</small></h3>
                        <svg id="chart1" width="900" height="400"></svg>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
                      <h3>Treemap <small>Lorem ipsum</small></h3>
                        <svg id="chart2" width="900" height="400"></svg>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
                        <h3>Donut Chart <small>Lorem ipsum</small></h3>
                        <svg id="chart3" width="900" height="400"></svg>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4">
                      <h3>Time Series <small>Lorem ipsum</small></h3>
                        <svg id="chart4" width="900" height="400"></svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change **li** class `nav-items` to `nav-item`.

**Explanation**: there is no class `nav-items`, see [Bootstrap 4 all css classes](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_ref_all_classes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Just change `nav-items` class to `nav-item`

`nav-items` class is invalid class as does not exist. modified code would be

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            Column Chart
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            Treemap
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            Donut Chart
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            Time Series
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> Just Copy and Past this Code
> ```

Let me know if its not working !

```
<div class="container"
<div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2>Charts</h2>
               <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            Column Chart
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            Treemap
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            Donut Chart
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                            Time Series
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tab1">
                      <h3>Column Chart <small>Lorem ipsum</small></h3>
                        <svg id="chart1" width="900" height="400"></svg>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
                      <h3>Treemap <small>Lorem ipsum</small></h3>
                        <svg id="chart2" width="900" height="400"></svg>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab3">
                        <h3>Donut Chart <small>Lorem ipsum</small></h3>
                        <svg id="chart3" width="900" height="400"></svg>
                    </div>
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tab4">
                      <h3>Time Series <small>Lorem ipsum</small></h3>
                        <svg id="chart4" width="900" height="400"></svg>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should add some explanation to your post.